# Como Inserir Lista com JPA

Tags: java, web-service, java-ee, jpa, tomcat

Boa tarde!

Estou fazendo um web service que recebe um Json do aplicativo, desencapsula e insere no banco de dados. Consigo desencapsular normalmente, o problema ocorre na hora de inseri os dados no banco de dados.

Tenho uma lista dentro um objeto e na hora de inserir, ele insere vários, em vez de apenas um objeto e aproveitar a chave para inserir os dados da lista.

Por exemplo, dentro do json mandado pelo usuário, tem uma lista de cômodos de um imovel, na hora de inserir esses cômodos, ele repete todo o resto.

Json recebido:

```
 `{"email":"teste@email.com","enderecoList":[{"bairroSetor":"Centro","cep":"877777770","cidade":"Palmas","complemento":"SN","estado":"TO","imovelList":[{"comodosList":[{"nome":"Garagem - Demoliçao de Muro"},{"nome":"Garagem - Construção de Muro"},{"nome":"Garagem - Regularização de Contrapiso"},{"nome":"Área Externa - Demoliçao de Muro"},{"nome":"Área Externa - Construção de Muro"},{"nome":"Área Externa - Regularização de Contrapiso"}],"tipo":"Casa"}],"ruaAlameda":"Rua 1"}],"horario":"Tarde","nome":"Teste","telefone":"(63) 98889-2200"}
`
```

**Métodos onde recebo json e insiro**

```
     @POST
    @Path("inserir")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void add(String content) {

        Gson g = new Gson();

        Usuario usuario = (Usuario) g.fromJson(content, Usuario.class);

        Usuario usuarioPersist = new Usuario();
        Endereco enderecoPersist = new Endereco();
        Imovel imovelPersist = new Imovel();
        Comodos comodoPersist = new Comodos();

        for (Endereco endereco : usuario.getEnderecoList()) {
            comodoPersist = new Comodos();
            for (Imovel imovel : endereco.getImovelList()) {
                for (Comodos comodo : imovel.getComodosList()) {

                    usuarioPersist.setEmail(usuario.getEmail());
                    usuarioPersist.setHorario(usuario.getHorario());
                    usuarioPersist.setNome(usuario.getNome());
                    usuarioPersist.setTelefone(usuario.getTelefone());

                    enderecoPersist.setBairroSetor(endereco.getBairroSetor());
                    enderecoPersist.setCep(endereco.getCep());
                    enderecoPersist.setCidade(endereco.getCidade());
                    enderecoPersist.setComplemento(endereco.getComplemento());
                    enderecoPersist.setEstado(endereco.getEstado());
                    enderecoPersist.setNumero(endereco.getNumero());
                    comodoPersist.setNome(comodo.getNome());
//                    comodos.add(comodoPersist);
                    imovelPersist.setTipo(imovel.getTipo());
                    enderecoPersist.setRuaAlameda(endereco.getRuaAlameda());

                    enderecoPersist.setUsuarioId(usuarioPersist);
                    imovelPersist.setEnderecoId(enderecoPersist);
                    comodoPersist.setImovelId(imovelPersist);

                    new ComodoRepository().save(comodoPersist);
                }

            }
```

**Classe ComodoRepository**

```
public class ComodoRepository extends GenericDAO<Comodos> {

    public ComodoRepository() {
        super(Comodos.class);
    }

}
```

**Classe GenericDAO**

```
 public abstract class GenericDAO<T extends Serializable> {

    private Class<T> aClass;

    protected GenericDAO(Class<T> aClass) {
        this.aClass = aClass;
        this.log = LogManager.getLogger(aClass.getName());;
    }

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return JPAUtil.getInstance().getEntityManager();
    }


      public void save(T entity) {
        EntityManager manager = getEntityManager();
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.persist(entity);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
        manager.close();
    }
```

**Solução**

Consegui chegar a solução inserindo primeiro a entidade Imovel, recuperando o id e setando na entidade Cômodo para a inserção da mesma separadamente.

```
 for (Endereco endereco : usuario.getEnderecoList()) {
            comodoPersist = new Comodos();
            for (Imovel imovel : endereco.getImovelList()) {
                usuarioPersist.setEmail(usuario.getEmail());
                usuarioPersist.setHorario(usuario.getHorario());
                usuarioPersist.setNome(usuario.getNome());
                usuarioPersist.setTelefone(usuario.getTelefone());

                enderecoPersist.setBairroSetor(endereco.getBairroSetor());
                enderecoPersist.setCep(endereco.getCep());
                enderecoPersist.setCidade(endereco.getCidade());
                enderecoPersist.setComplemento(endereco.getComplemento());
                enderecoPersist.setEstado(endereco.getEstado());
                enderecoPersist.setNumero(endereco.getNumero());

                imovelPersist.setTipo(imovel.getTipo());
                enderecoPersist.setRuaAlameda(endereco.getRuaAlameda());

                enderecoPersist.setUsuarioId(usuarioPersist);
                imovelPersist.setEnderecoId(enderecoPersist);

                imovelRepository.salvar(imovelPersist);
                Imovel imovelId = new ImovelRepository().findById(imovelPersist.getId());

                for (Comodos comodo : imovel.getComodosList()) {

                    comodoPersist.setNome(comodo.getNome());
                    comodoPersist.setImovelId(imovelId);
                    comodoRepository.salvar(comodoPersist);
                }

            }

        }
```

Também adicionei o método findById na classe GenericDAO.

```
public T findById(Integer id) {
    EntityManager manager = getEntityManager();
    manager.getTransaction().begin();

    T entity = (T) manager.find(aClass, id);

    manager.getTransaction().commit();
    manager.close();

    return entity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive um problema familiar, no meu caso meu objeto não estava compactado então coloquei @GZIP

@POST
@GZIP
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response saveData(@GZIP RecievingData customer);

Comment: Acho que compactar não irá resolver meu problema.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta com a solução.